# How to find out how to change the text in the checkbox when checked?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. How to find out how to change the text in the checkbox when checked?

For example I have a check box that is not checked and beside it, it says "I do not accept terms" and I want to change that to "I do accept terms" when the check box is checked.

Comment: Don't get fancy about this. Simply leave "I do accept the terms". If checked, it means that you agree, If not... not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            checkBox.setText("I do accept terms");
        } else {
            checkBox.setText("I do not accept terms");
        }
    }
});
```